# Export XML data as JSON in Talend

Tags: json, talend

In Talend, I have a job that received XML messages (of different structures) and call a web service with those messages. The tRestClient component automatically transforms the Xml into JSON when it calls my web service.

In case of an error, I want to save my message locally in JSON. Is there a component in Talend to automatically transform the XML into JSON (like the tRestClient do)?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if the `tRestClient` component is converting XML to JSON or if you told the component to only accept JSON.

Comment: I told the component to accept JSON and in my web service, the message I receive is in JSON.

Comment: Then this assumption *The tRestClient component automatically transforms the Xml into JSON* is incorrect, I suppose. The way could be another: You could check if you can use `tXMLMap` to map all data and write it with `tWriteJSONField` to some place.